# Difference between Owner.Id vs OwnerId

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, ownership

Trying to write some test code for a custom object and its controller class. I noticed that one of my methods which depends on the ownership of an object was bugging out and I discovered that Owner.Id and OwnerId are returning different values.
Are they supposed to be different? which one am I suppoed to use? Here is an example.

```
    Conversation__C convA = new Conversation__C();
    convA.FromNumber__c = '1231231231';
    convA.ToNumber__c = '2342342342';
    insert convA;
    List<Conversation__c> conversationsT = [Select OwnerId, Owner.Id from Conversation__c ];
    for (Conversation__c c : conversationsT)
        System.debug(c.Owner.Id + ' ' + c.OwnerId);
```

returns

```
09:38:01:200 USER_DEBUG [68]|DEBUG|null mySalesforceID
```

The strange thing is that both return the same data in production!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `OwnerId`. I am not sure why there is a difference in values, and will try to reproduce. But there is no reason to introduce a cross-object reference when all you need is the `Id` value itself.

One example why `Owner.Id` is less preferable:

```
system.debug(c.get('OwnerId')); // works
system.debug(c.get('Owner.Id')); // fails
```

You can get the cross-reference to work, but it's definitely more complicated.

Another reason it's less preferable is that you can't set it that way. Might as well be consistent.

```
c.OwnerId = idValue; // works
c.Owner.Id = idValue; // cannot update in this manner
```